# Draw radar chart with different sector sizes in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, radar-chart

I want to draw radar chart with different sector sizes like this

[image: Radar Chart]

I tried using Chart component and got

[image: this]

Is there a way to change sector size in WinForms radar chart or maybe there is a library with component that allows to do that? I prefer WinForms component, but Wpf component is also OK for me.

```
Series radarSeries = new Series("RadarChart");
radarSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Radar;

radarSeries.Points.AddXY(0, 4);
radarSeries.Points.AddXY(75, 3);
radarSeries.Points.AddXY(90, 2);
radarSeries.Points.AddXY(140, 5);
radarSeries.Points.AddXY(190, 3);
radarSeries.Points.AddXY(270, 4);
radarSeries.Points.AddXY(330, 2);

chart.Series.Add(radarSeries);
```

Comment: so that would mean that you want to points to be displayed by arrows or something else rather then by a scaled sector boundary? actualy in your plot you have no sector boundaries but scaled axes

Comment: the closer to the original chart the better. Points displayed by arrows would be a huge bonus, scaled axes is key priority.